# how get degree of node's in protocol CBRP in ns2

Tags: protocols, ns2, degrees

I want to get  degree a node's in protocol CBRP,
How can I get a degree node's (number of neighbors a node's) in the CBRP protocol in ns2.35?
 thanks

Comment: May be this will help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586478/how-to-find-neighbor-list-in-ns2

Comment: @Knud Larsen  Thanks for attention but  I want this code in C ++

Comment: i calculated it in ntable.cc with this way, but give me an error:'//int
NeighborTable::degree() {
 int degree = 0;
          adjtable_ent::iterator neighbor_ ;
 for ( neighbor_ = adjtable_ent.begin(); neighbor_ != adjtable_ent.end(); ++neighbor_) {
   
    degree++;
  }
          
 return degree;
}

Answer (score 0):

recognize ClusterHeads in file trace.tr CBRP

Hi
Can it diagnose the clusterhead in the trace.tr file protocol cbrp